# Angular named router outlet link does not

Tags: javascript, angular, router-outlet

While using router outlets in Angular I'm facing some problems.

I want to have a link like "maintopic/subtopicHeadline/subtopic", where I set the routes like this:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: AppComponent },

  {
    path: ':maintopic',
    component: SidenavMainComponent
  },
 
  {
    path: ':subtopicHeadline/:subtopic',
    component: ContentHandlerComponent,
    outlet: 'content'
  },
];
```

I get the values for the subtopicheadline and the subtopic correctly, but I don't know how to set the link for the router outlet. For now it is `[routerLink]="['',{outlets:{content:[subtopic]}}]"` but there I only get a link like "/subtopic". How must the link be written to reach the desired format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these videos - it is quite easy to Google it:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9fH09nJGm-U
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5gF8Jjsv18U